OS crashed after attempt to install Resolve
I was trying to install davinci resolve and when I tried to run it, it gave me a bunch of repositories to install. I got libasound2 and when I install that, my screen went black and on restart I was in terminal. I ran
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
and after that nothing is working. I try to use vlc media player and it doesnt work, I try to open settings and it doesnt work. Nautilus broke and I tried all the fixes on the internet to no success so I installed nemo. I havent checked what else isnt working but I would greatly appreciate some help.

Several keys bits of info missing from the question. Please edit and add at least the following. 1. What was the command you used to install Resolve? 2. List all the repositories you were told to add. 3. Most important the version of Ubuntu you are using.  4. List all the fixes you tried from the internet. At this point I would suggest you reinstall the OS and before doing this again be sure that the app is right for the OS.

and next: start vlc from command line and watch errors to show; search those; fix those :)

Well I don't know why people are downvoting you when this is beyond stupid at this point, a single command to delete half of the system should never be the case.
WARNING DO NOT PASTE THESE: I guess you used either of these 2 commands to brick your system. For me the first one broke everything.
sudo apt-get install liboss4-salsa-asound2
or
sudo apt-get install libasound2t64
For me using the first one literally deleted everything. Lucky for me the console was open and I had the list of all removed packages. Saved the list and just did
sudo apt-get install -y package1 package2 etc.. but before that I had to reinstall kubuntu with sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
The damage was then minimal, couple of settings lost, items in the menu and librewolf.
I know 1 month passed for you but this answer now ranks on google so I had to at least write how i fixed my problem, hopefully you've fixed yours. I'll report the issue and I can't believe trying to install davinci ended up having to deal with this.

I encountered the same sequence by executing "apt-get remove libasound2". I recovered my system by entering recovery mode, select dpkg(recover all packages to the beginning state), then reboot the system, the desktop environment was working normally.
